# Microsoft partner generate token

Tags: python, azure, api, token

Using python I did this. But not able to generate tokens that can help to get customer data.
Code to get access token

```
url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+tanat_id+"/oauth2/token"
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "return-client-request-id": "true",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    "Host": "login.microsoftonline.com",
    "Content-Length": "194",
    "Expect": "100-continue"
}
data = {
    'client_id': client_id,
    'resource': 'https://api.partner.microsoft.com',
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
}

res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
access_token = json.loads(res.text)["access_token"]
```

Code to generate a token

```
url = "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/generatetoken"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + str(access_token),
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
}
data = {
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
}

res = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data={"grant_type":"jwt_token"})
```

But

```
>>> res.text
'{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid token: tokenValidationResult == null - True, tokenValidationResult.Principal == null - True, tokenValidationResult.Principal.Identity == null- True, tokenValidationResult.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated - "}'
```

Using access_token if I try to get customer list it returns a 401 error.

```
#Customer List

url = "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers?size=40"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + str(access_token),
    "Accept": "application/json",
}

res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
res
<Response [401]>
res.text
""
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch the first access token from https://graph.windows.net

```
data = {
    'client_id': client_id,
    'resource': 'https://graph.windows.net',
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
}
```

Kindly check the request headers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/partner-center-authentication?redirectedfrom=MSDN#rest-app-only-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

The first error "error": "invalid_grant" is because of the permissions, this usually occurs when it’s been long that the credentials got refreshed or Give a try with below steps:

•   Select "Azure: Sign in"

•   Removed the linked account.

•   Add the account back.

401 is Unauthorized error: This error often means that the access token may be missing in the HTTP authenticate request header or that the token is invalid or has expired

For these common errors refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/resolve-auth-errors)