# Microsoft partner API: can't authenticate

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, microsoft-partnercenter-java

I've created an app in Azure AD and followed this steps (Application and user access): https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/partner-rest/blob/docs/partner-rest/develop/api-authentication.md

From what I understand the Microsoft Partner API only works with MFA, so I can't authenticate using username + password to https://login.microsoftonline.com.

To get an `access_code`, I perform these steps:

1. Open the url in my browser: https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://****/test.php&response_mode=form_post&scope=offline_access%20openid%20profile%20User.Read&state=1
2. On the callback url, I receive a code, which I use to request the `access_code`.
   I perform the following request:

```
curl --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
--data-urlencode 'resource=https://api.partner.microsoft.com' \
--data-urlencode 'code=CODE_FROM_PREVIOUS_REQUEST' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=https://****/test.php'
```

Now I have the `access_code` and the `refresh_token`

3. This is where I'm stuck, I use the `access_token` in the following request:

```
curl --request GET 'https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN'
```

But I get an 401 invalid_grant error.
I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68897504/microsoft-partner-generate-token) article from a similar problem, but that didn't help.

Comment: Try passing resource as `4990cffe-04e8-4e8b-808a-1175604b879f/user_impersonation` or `https://api.partner.microsoft-int.com/user_impersonation` and generate the access token.

Comment: Thank you for this. With your first resource I receive a token, but when I use this access token with the Partner Center API, I still get the 401 invalid_grant error.

Comment: Did you try using this resource`https://api.partner.microsoft-int.com/user_impersonation`?

Comment: While generating the code you have used v2 endpoint and while generating token you have used v1 endpoint. Make sure to use same endpoint.

Comment: I tried using v1 or v2 for both, but that's also not working.
Also when I try resource `https://api.partner.microsoft-int.com/user_impersonation` I get this error:
AADSTS500011: The resource principal named resourcehttps://api.partner.microsoft-int.com/user_impersonation was not found in the tenant

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `refresh_token` in the call to the Partner Center API instead of an `ACCESS_TOKEN`. I had a similar issue and was able to bypass the 401 `invalid_grant` error with this.